# How can I use setlocale function out of main function in C?

Tags: c, setlocale

I'm trying to use Turkish letters in a structure. I coded setlocale function in main function. But when I compiled codes, I'm getting error from Turkish letters in the structure. How can I solve that problem? I tried some solution ways but they didn't work. Does structure must include just Latin alphabet? I hope I could explain my problem clearly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <locale.h>

struct quiz {

    int soru_ID[20];

    char soru_metni[600];

    char şık_A[300];

    char şık_B[300];

    char şık_C[300];

    char şık_D[300];

    char doğru_cevap[300];

} yd;

int main(){

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");
// I keep coding here.
}
```

Comment: `setlocale()` affects the locale in which your compiled program operates at run time. It doesn't affect what characters the compiler accepts as letters in your source code. Look for an option specific to your compiler (which one are you using?).

Comment: `How can I solve that problem?` Use another compiler. `Does structure must include just Latin alphabet?` Kind-of, yes.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. @KamilCuk

Comment: More info: [Identifier - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/identifier)